# SSH Key generated, still ask for password

Tags: ssh

I try to use OpenSSH on a Windows R2012 server to connect a Linux server without password, what I've done so far: run `ssh-keygen -t rsa`; Copy the `id_rsa.pub` to linux server. Then I run `ssh username@hostname` but it still ask me password. Here's the debug message:

```
ssh  tsdev@hostname -v
OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.0p1, LibreSSL 2.6.5
debug1: Connecting to hostname  [hostname ] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\UserName/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\UserName/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\UserName/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\UserName/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\UserName/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\UserName/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\UserName/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\UserName/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\UserName/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\UserName/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.0
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.3
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.3 pat OpenSSH_5* compat 0x0c000002
debug1: Authenticating to hostname :22 as 'tsdev'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ssh-rsa
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: aes128-ctr MAC: umac-64@openssh.com compress
ion: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: aes128-ctr MAC: umac-64@openssh.com compress
ion: none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(2048<3072<8192) sent
debug1: got SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: got SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ssh-rsa SHA256:iPIV2C3o7iAWctj17etTxHdcbPLJjLvWR5pbhQyJ
VsU
debug1: Host 'hostname ' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in C:\\Users\\UserName/.ssh/known_hosts:2
debug1: rekey out after 4294967296 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey in after 4294967296 blocks
debug1: Will attempt key: C:\\Users\\UserName\\.ssh\\id_rsa RSA SHA256:+6FE/fz08
CxtJQkbSzk4pm2xcJc/bsa2txF7ng2u3RQ agent
debug1: Will attempt key: C:\\Users\\UserName/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:cxtm55sHmeJ
H2dPeTBY3VSnV9BuL58xMT94nTpn5PtE
debug1: Will attempt key: C:\\Users\\UserName/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Will attempt key: C:\\Users\\UserName/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Will attempt key: C:\\Users\\UserName/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Will attempt key: C:\\Users\\UserName/.ssh/id_xmss
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mi
c,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: C:\\Users\\UserName\\.ssh\\id_rsa RSA SHA256:+6FE/f
z08CxtJQkbSzk4pm2xcJc/bsa2txF7ng2u3RQ agent
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mi
c,password
debug1: Offering public key: C:\\Users\\UserName/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:cxtm55sH
meJH2dPeTBY3VSnV9BuL58xMT94nTpn5PtE
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mi
c,password
debug1: Trying private key: C:\\Users\\UserName/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: C:\\Users\\UserName/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: C:\\Users\\UserName/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Trying private key: C:\\Users\\UserName/.ssh/id_xmss
debug1: Next authentication method: password
debug1: read_passphrase: can't open /dev/tty: No such file or directory
```

Can anyone give any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: Just to be sure: Did you really copy `id_rsa.pub` as in `scp id_rsa.pub user@server:~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` or run `ssh-copy-id user@server`?

Comment: I use Winscp to copy the id_rsa.pub to the ~./ssh/authorized_keys, since my Windows server did not recognize the 'ssh-copy-id'

Comment: Might there be a problem regarding EOL characters between Win and Linux? Does `cat -A authorized_keys` return any `^M$`.

Answer (score 1):

It does look like your client (on the Windows Box) is trying to use the private key as it should, and the server is simply not accepting it.  So the problem is most likely (Linux) server-side.

It's not clear from your question exactly what you've done to "copy id_rsa.pub onto the server".  But since you've not stated it explicitly I believe you may not have done the right thing with it

Assuming the server us using OpenSSH with a default configuration, you need to place the public key in a file called `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` where `~` is your home directory.  If you only want that one public key then you can just rename the file otherwise you can copy the contents of `id_rsa.pub` into your `authorized_keys` file:

```
cat id_rsa.pub >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

You may also need to check the security on that file.  It must not have read permissions for "group" and other.  You can set the permissions with:

```
# Either set numbered permissions: read write for user, nothing for group other
chmod 600 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys

# or remove Read Write eXecute permissions from Group and Other
chmod go-rwx ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

Comment: Using `ssh-copy-id user@server` might be simpler than manually adding it to `authorized_keys`

Comment: I have done the copy the id_rsa.pub to the ~/.ssh/authorized_keys with Winscp, I was tried to use ssh-copy-id, but I got a not recognized error, so I use Winscp to copy the id_rsa.pub. And the security of the authorized_keys is 640. It's not working. I use OpenSSH 8.0 on Windows side. And OpenSSH5.3p1 on linux side, could it be the version issue?